# PartialView não carregando no padrão do select2

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2, partialview

Estou com um problema quando chamo minha PartialView, o mesmo carrega todos os dados na View mas não no formato certo (layout) do select2, no caso seria quando clicar no input aparecesse os dados, atualmente está carregando todos na tela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ex de uma View que utilizo e carrega certo o select2.

[image]

Creio que seja algo de css, mas estou referenciando ambos do selec2 mas mesmo assim não está funcionando.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/separate/vendor/select2.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/separate/vendor/blockui.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/lib/blockUI/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>

 <div class="col-lg-1">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label>Contrato:</label>
                @Html.DropDownList("contrato", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "select2", @multiple = "multiple" })
            </div>
        </div>

<script src="~/Scripts/lib/select2/select2.full.min.js"></script>
```

A chamada da Partial:

```
function addCliente() {
    var data = $("Form").serializeArray();
    $.post("/EmailMarketing/AddCliente", data, function (ret) {
        $("#addClienteBody").html(ret);
    });
    $('#modalAddCliente').modal('show');
}
```

Comment: Como você faz a chamada da `PartialView`?

Comment: Adicionado a pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conforme documentação do [select2](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage), é necessário iniciar o componente, na sua `PartialView` adicione o seguinte código

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.select2').select2();
});
```

Não estou certo se irá funcionar por conta do método como está chamando sua `partial`, abaixo segue uma segunda solução:

```
function addCliente() {
    var data = $("Form").serializeArray();
    $("#addClienteBody").load("/EmailMarketing/AddCliente", data, function () {
        $('.select2').select2();
    })
}
```

Desta forma, após ele fazer o `load` da sua `partial` ele irá carregar o método de inicialização do `select2`

obs: nesse segundo caso não é necessário ter o método de inicialização na `partial`

Comment: Consegui referenciando os scripts na View do Create e adicionando apenas o document.ready na partial, vlw.

Comment: Show, não se esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita.